# How do I set the default value of an input box using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, forms, reset

I want to change the default value of an input box such that when I reset the form, the value remains.

I have the following code that sets a value using jQuery but as reset is pressed, the value becomes the initial one.

```
<form>
    Email: <input type="text" id="email" value="old value" />
    <input type="reset" value="reset" />
</form>
```

```
$(function(){
    $("#email").val("New value");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset clears all values of the form (default behaviour). If you want the values to be visible again, you need to set them again. So you need to call a method onclick of the reset button and fill the form again.

Comment: it not correct answer , @Sergey Larionov answer is better, and another way to do it would be  $("#email").prop("defaultValue", "New value")

Answer (score 34):

You have to set attribute "value" of #email element, not the value itself.

```
$("#email").attr("value", "New value");
```

Comment: You can set the value directly with .val() you dont have to set the attribute yourself .val() is basically an alias for .attr("value", "new value");

Comment: No, it's not an alias. Here is .fn.val: 

    this.value = val; // doesn't modify DOM

and here is attr:
    elem.setAttribute( name, "" + value ); //modifies DOM

Comment: This is a better answer than the accepted one. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Reset by default clears a form but if you want to controll this behaviour yourself here is how you would do it. You need to use .val() Here are some examples of doing a single box reset and multiple box's using a wrapped set.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/HenryGarle/ZTprm/

```
<b>Reset Single</b>

<input type="text" id="TextBox">
<button id="reset">Reset</button>

<hr>
<b>Reset Many</b>

<div id="Many">
<input type="text" value="1">
<input type="text" value="5">
<input type="text" value="2">
    <button id="ResetMany">Reset</button>
</div>


<script>
// Reset single
$("#reset").click(function (e) {
   $("#TextBox").val("Value"); 
});


// Resets many given a selector 
// Could be a form, containing div
$("#ResetMany").click(function (e) {
    var inputs = $("input", "#Many");

    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        $(inputs[i]).val("Value");
    }

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('input[type="reset"]').click(function(){
 $("#email").val("New value");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put the value then you can do as @Sergey Larionov mentioned. If you want to put a default placeholder you can do this:

```
$("#email").attr("placeholder", "Default value");
```