# How to restore the default value(i.e. today's date or current date) of input box having date when clicked on reset button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input field that contains date. I have set the default value of this input field to today's date or current date. I also have a 'Reset' button on my page. Is there any way to set the input field to the default value (i.e. current date) again after clicking on the reset button?

I have this code, but whenever I click on reset button the input field is set to blank. I tried using '.click' but it doesn't work either.

html:

```
<label>Order Date: </label>
<div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
    <input type="text" class="datepicker" />
</div>

<button type="reset" id="resetBtn">Reset</button>
```

jquery:

```
 jQuery('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
        timepicker: false,
        format:'d-M-Y',
        value: new Date()
    });
```

Comment: Add onClick listener on Reset Button and in that listener set value of input to new Date()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set the default value of an input box using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157896/how-do-i-set-the-default-value-of-an-input-box-using-jquery)

Comment: Use `$('.datepicker').datepicker('setDate', 'today');` inside onClick event listener.

Comment: adding onclick did not work :(

Comment: @user1381262 Check answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker('setDate','today');` inside onClick event listener.

```js
$( function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker('setDate','today');
  } );
  $("#resetBtn").on('click',function(){
  $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker('setDate','today');
  })
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<label>Order Date: </label>
<div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
    <input type="text" class="datepicker" />
</div>
<button type="reset" id="resetBtn">Reset</button>
```

Comment: Welcome. You can upvote the answer so that other people can get help for same issue.

Comment: since I am new here, I cannot vote, but I have marked the answer that it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a new date using `.datepicker('setdate', ... )`

---

## Demo

```js
// Initialise datepicker
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  format: 'd-M-Y',
  value: new Date()
});


// Click event to the button
$("#resetBtn").click(function() {

  // Change date of the datepicker
  // Can't just change the .val() as this isn't recognised in the correct date formate
  $('.datepicker').datepicker('setDate', new Date());
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js
"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">


<label>Order Date: </label>
<div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
  <input type="text" class="datepicker" />
</div>

<button type="reset" id="resetBtn">Reset</button> jquery:
```